# AngularJS: Validate in a Modal - Minimum Date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to validate a date input, and my min date check just isn't working. Would appreciate the assist.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="instructor-form.html">
    <form name="instructorForm" novalidate ng-submit="ok('save')">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 ng-hide="!item.InstructorId">Edit Instructor</h3>
            <h3 ng-hide="item.InstructorId">New Instructor</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span5">
                    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: instructorForm.lic.$invalid && instructorForm.lic.$dirty}">
                        <label for="lic">License Expiration Date *</label>
                        <div class="input-prepend input-block-level">
                            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                            <input name="lic" type="date" ng-model="item.LicenseExp" required min="1900-01-01">
                        </div>
                        <span ng-show="instructorForm.lic.$dirty">
                            <span ng-show="instructorForm.lic.$error.required" class="help-inline">License Exp. is required</span>
                        </span>
                        <span ng-show="instructorForm.lic.$error.min">Not a valid date! Please enter a date after 1900.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <span ng-show="instructorForm.$invalid">* Please enter all required information before saving.</span>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="instructorForm.$invalid" type="submit">Save</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</script>
```

instructorForm.lic.$error.min is where I'm having problems. .$dirty and .$error.required work just fine, but .$error.min doesn't seem to do squat.

The controller code:

```
$scope.editInstructor = function (orig) {
    dialogScope.item = angular.copy(orig);
    dialogScope.item.LicenseExp = moment(orig.LicenseExp).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    var modal = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'instructor-form.html',
        controller: 'ModalCtrl',
        resolve: { childScope: function () { return dialogScope; } }
    });

    modal.result.then(function (result) {
        if (result === 'save') {
            var absMinDate = new moment('1900-01-01');

            if (moment(absMinDate).isBefore(dialogScope.item.LicenseExp)) {
                // set in our collection for immediate user feedback
                $scope.instructors[idxof(orig)] = dialogScope.item;
                pubSub.publish('highlight', orig.InstructorId);

                // call service to save on server
                dialogScope.item.$save(function(updated) {
                    if (updated.error) {
                        // if failure, reset original in collection
                        $scope.instructors[idxof(orig)] = orig;
                        pubSub.publish('highlight', orig.InstructorId);

                        // show error
                        notificationService.error('<h4>An error occurred updating the instructor.</h4>' + updated.error);
                    } else {
                        // if success, show message
                        notificationService.success('Instructor updated successfully.');
                        cacheManager.removeResource('instructor');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // show error
                // notificationService.error('<h4>Please enter a date after January 1st, 1900.</h4>');
                // This doesn't work, as it shuts the modal and then displays an error - useless to the user.
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: can you post your controller code

Comment: It's pretty long, but sure... lemme see...

Comment: I just need read where you set `instructorForm.lic.$error.min`

Comment: I'm not really sure about the whole "where you set" part - I'm so new to Angular that I wouldn't say I'm actually even new to it yet. I didn't have to set `instructorForm.lic.$invalid` or `instructorForm.lic.$dirty` - why would I have to set `instructorForm.lic.$error.min`?

Comment: You don't have to set it. Angular has built-in support for the min attribute on [date inputs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D).

Comment: @vrmc - That was the exact page I was using to figure out how to set these things up - but min just doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: @vrmc  is right, i forgot it.

Comment: I pasted your form into a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yCXQIXezUzoLk8nthv9z?p=preview) and it seems to work. Maybe something in your controller is screwing it up? Anyway, date inputs are only supported in Chrome so I'm not sure you want to use one.

Comment: Is it possible that the fact that it's in a modal could be causing the problem?